# @mui/system --Grid-columns css var is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I've been ripping my hair for a couple of days trying to solve this now.
We have a react application where we're using `styled-components` and we wanted to add `@mui/system` to take advantage of their nice `Grid` component (Grid v2 to be precise).
We have installed `@mui/system` and set it up according to the documentation to use `styled-components` as the styled-engine (using `styled-engine-sc`).
So far so good.
But when we run the app and try using the `Grid` component, it doesn't work as expected and all grid elements span across the entire viewport.
Doing a quick inspect shows that the css var `--Grid-columns` is undefined (see image) and I can't find how to get those css vars to be injected in our app when using just `@mui/system` and `styled-components` as styled-engine.

Update: Further investigations show that using `@mui/material` package instead of just `@mui/system` does not help either, so the problem seems to be lying in using `styled-components` as the styled-engine.

But why that affects the css vars that should be injected by @mui baffles me.

[image: --Grid-columns is not defined]

Here's our setup:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mui/system": "^5.11.8",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@latest",
...
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@mui/styled-engine": ["./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine-sc"]
    }
  }
...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@material-ui/styled-engine': '@material-ui/styled-engine-sc',
    },
  },
...
```

And finally the component where we use the Grid.

```
...
import Grid from '@mui/system/Unstable_Grid';
import ThemeProvider from '@mui/system/ThemeProvider';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/system';

const Root () => {
  const { useSelectedFlightState } = store;
  const theme = createTheme();

  return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <Grid container spacing={2} xs={12} sm={10} smOffset={1}>
       <Grid xs={12} sm={8}>
        ....
       </Grid>
       <Grid xs={12} sm={4}>
       ....
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
   </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with emotion. If it helps, it only seems to happen to me when I am rendering to a `<Portal />` either a self built one or the one at `import Portal from "@mui/material/Portal";`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up using @emotion as styled-engine instead of styled-components. That solved my issue - but I had to convert a few components from using SC to using @emotion/styled instead.

Comment: `<Grid container columns={12} />` fixes this in my Portal related case. Looking at `Unstable_Grid2`'s code the virtual DOM maps through nested grids and sets the `columns` value but this isn't happening within the Portal for some reason! Presumptively because the child grid is only a child of the parent in the virtual DOM. In the actual DOM it is portalled to elsewhere.